# JS: is there a way to adhere to an order using a Map?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I want to use a `map` to store some data but I want to preserve the order in which they come from the API array:

```
let people = [{ name: "jordan", age: 33}, { name: "rich", age: 23} ]; // comes from API

let map = new Map();

for (let x = 0; x < people.length; x++) {
     map.set(person.name, person.age) 
}
```

I now have a map of those:

```
// console.log(map) 

// Map(2) {'jordan' => 33, 'rich' => 23}
```

if I iterate through that map later on using a `for of` loop, is the order of the Entries guaranteed in that I would be sure the first `age` would always be `33`?

Comment: Yes it is guaranteed. ``The keys in Map are ordered in a simple, straightforward way: A Map object iterates entries, keys, and values in the order of entry insertion``. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#:~:text=The%20keys%20in%20Map%20are%20ordered%20in%20a%20simple%2C%20straightforward%20way%3A%20A%20Map%20object%20iterates%20entries%2C%20keys%2C%20and%20values%20in%20the%20order%20of%20entry%20insertion.)

Comment: A more flexible option might be to map from each entry's `name` to the entry itself (within the `people` array). Then you could lookup any entry by `name` and immediately get to *any* of its attributes (including `age` e.g. `map.get('rich').age`).